# JSON file coming up fine from the URL but wont allow me to grab it with $.getJSON (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml

```
(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=AAPL&callback=?', function(){console.log("function was run");});
  });
}())
```

I just started working with APIs two days ago. I can't figure out why this isn't working.  When I put the link in my browser the JSON comes up no problem.  If I omit the '&callback=?' part at the end of the url (which I would do if it were JSON instead of JSONP), I get the error message

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=AAPL.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I need to do this for a coding camp application that I need to finish for this weekend, so if the specifics as to why this won't work are most likely incomprehensible to someone of as little experience as me, if you could simply instruct me how I can get the json file from their server to an object I can work with in Javascript I would greatly appreciate it (although I would like to learn from this if you can explain it in n00b terms).  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying JSON as the format for that api, when you should be specifying JSONP. [See the api documentation](http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/).

To fix it just change:

```
v2/Quote/json?
```

to:

```
v2/Quote/jsonp?
```

Working demo:

```js
(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
        document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify( data, null, '\t' ) + '</pre>';
    } );
  });
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: he asking about why he got this error from the api if he use the json link all what he need to do is append the url at the end of the callback instead of ?

Comment: @AlaaAbuzaghleh He just needs to tell the api's server that he wants to use JSONP (since jsonp works cross-domain). For that particular api the way to do that is to change `/json` to `/jsonp`. jQuery will handle naming the callback function and passing the data to his callback, see the demo in my edited post.

Answer (score -1):

i think this related to the CORS, if you are the developer of this API or if you have access to it all what you need to do is

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if you are not the developer for this API, then you can call it by the following

http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=AAPL&callback=http-URL